# Multi value Dictionary

Tags: c#

How would i create a multi value Dictionary in c#?

E.g. `Dictionary<T,T,T>` where the first T is the key and other two are values.

so this would be possible: `Dictionary<int,object,double>`

Thanks

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Just create a `Pair<TFirst, TSecond>` type and use that as your value.

I have an example of one in my [C# in Depth source code](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx). Reproduced here for simplicity:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public sealed class Pair<TFirst, TSecond>
    : IEquatable<Pair<TFirst, TSecond>>
{
    private readonly TFirst first;
    private readonly TSecond second;

    public Pair(TFirst first, TSecond second)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public TFirst First
    {
        get { return first; }
    }

    public TSecond Second
    {
        get { return second; }
    }

    public bool Equals(Pair<TFirst, TSecond> other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return EqualityComparer<TFirst>.Default.Equals(this.First, other.First) &&
               EqualityComparer<TSecond>.Default.Equals(this.Second, other.Second);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        return Equals(o as Pair<TFirst, TSecond>);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return EqualityComparer<TFirst>.Default.GetHashCode(first) * 37 +
               EqualityComparer<TSecond>.Default.GetHashCode(second);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage over a normal KeyValuePair? Is there some kind of overhead when using a KeyValuePair?

Comment: Mainly it's a difference in emphasis - while KeyValuePair does indeed encapsulate a pair of values, it implies a particular kind of relationship between them... this doen't.

Comment: Is this the same as Tuple in .Net 4.0?

Comment: @adam0101: Much the same, yes.

Comment: I found the simplest way is using a Dictionary<int, Object> and using Anonymouse type to fill the Object.

Comment: @BasselAlkhateeb: If you don't like being able to get the values back, then yes, that's fine...

Comment: @JonSkeet, [what is the rationale for using an immutable value in a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733406/why-would-you-use-an-immutable-value-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: @JonSkeet I'll have my cake and eat it too. `T RecoverType( object o, T t )
{
 return (T)o;
}
var o = (object)(new { t1 = 1, t2 = "a" });
var t = RecoverType( o, new { t1 = 0, t2 = "b" } );`

Answer (score 78):

If you are trying to group values together this may be a great opportunity to create a simple struct or class and use that as the value in a dictionary.

```
public struct MyValue
{
    public object Value1;
    public double Value2;
}
```

then you could have your dictionary

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, MyValue>();
```

you could even go a step further and implement your own dictionary class that will handle any special operations that you would need. for example if you wanted to have an Add method that accepted an int, object, and double

```
public class MyDictionary : Dictionary<int, MyValue>
{
    public void Add(int key, object value1, double value2)
    {
        MyValue val;
        val.Value1 = value1;
        val.Value2 = value2;
        this.Add(key, val);
    }
}
```

then you could simply instantiate and add to the dictionary like so and you wouldn't have to worry about creating 'MyValue' structs:

```
var dict = new MyDictionary();
dict.Add(1, new Object(), 2.22);
```

Answer (score 36):

```
Dictionary<T1, Tuple<T2, T3>>
```

Edit: Sorry - I forgot you don't get Tuples until .NET 4.0 comes out. D'oh!

Comment: Tuples are in .NET 4.0 BCL, and it's not related to C# 4.0. C# 4.0 features have no mention about tuple support. Please correct your answer.

Comment: The problem with the tuple is the values aren't named.

Comment: Furthermore Tuple values are readonly, which might be ok for some cases, but should be considered before using them.

Comment: Very good information.  Allowed me to extend existing dictionary code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is quite overkill for a dictionary semantics, since dictionary is by definition is a collection of keys and its respective values, just like the way we see a book of language dictionary that contains a word as the key and its descriptive meaning as the value.

But you can represent a dictionary that can contain collection of values, for example:

```
Dictionary<String,List<Customer>>
```

Or a dictionary of a key and the value as a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Customer,Dictionary<Order,OrderDetail>>
```

Then you'll have a dictionary that can have multiple values.

Comment: As soon as you start nesting dictionaries, your code starts looking like multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @IAbstract it's not that similar in semantics. Multi dimensional arrays do not care about the combination of key-values. Also Multi dimensional arrays do not care about the maximum element of two (just like dictionary must have).

Comment: @eriawan: I don't think I was clear :) ...assume int values for keys: `myColl[0][1]` ... *looks **like*** a multi-dimensional array. When you start nesting collections, I believe it is time to encapsulate the 'value' collection appropriately.

Comment: @IAbstract that's a good point! Now I understand your point in your last comment. I agree we should encapsulate the value collection properly.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can do that directly. You could create a class containing both your `object` and `double` and put an instance of it in the dictionary though.

```
class Pair
{
    object obj;
    double dbl;
}

Dictionary<int, Pair> = new Dictionary<int, Pair>();
```

Comment: 1+ this is great solution

Answer (score 2):

If the values are related, why not encapsulate them in a class and just use the plain old Dictionary?

Comment: Will be more readable than Pair and Tuple as well. What is First, Second, Item1, Item2?

Answer (score 2):

I solved Using:

```
Dictionary<short, string[]>
```

Like this

```
Dictionary<short, string[]> result = new Dictionary<short, string[]>();
result.Add(1,
           new string[] 
                    { 
                    "FirstString",
                    "Second"
                    }
                );
        }
return result;
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but - since it's not been mentioned this works

```
  Dictionary<string, object> LookUp = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  LookUp.Add("bob", new { age = "23", height = "2.1m", weight = "110kg"});
  LookUp.Add("jasper", new { age = "33", height = "1.75m", weight = "90kg"});
  foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in LookUp )
  {
      object person = entry.Value;
      Console.WriteLine("Person name:" + entry.Key + " Age: "  + person.age);          
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You describe a multimap.

You can make the value a List object, to store more than one value (>2 for extensibility).

Override the dictionary object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of a single key to multi value map in C# which uses a set based key type:

https://github.com/ColmBhandal/CsharpExtras/blob/master/CsharpExtras/Dictionary/MultiValueMapImpl.cs

The dictionary behaves like a regular dictionary from the key type onto a set of the value type, but also provides functionality to directly add a single value of the value type, and in the background handles the creation of an underlying set and/or addition to that set.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this out there since it seems to be by far the simplest way of handling this:

```
   public static Dictionary<string, (int, string)> Points = new Dictionary<string, (int, string)>
    {
    {"Key", (100, "Value Text")}
}
```

And for retrieving value from the dictionary, there's "Item1" and "Item2" which is a bit weird but seems to be working:

```
int example = dictionary[key].Item1;
string exampleText = dictionary[key].Item2;
```