# Something like Dictionary but can store more than one value?

Tags: c#, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multi value Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569903/multi-value-dictionary)

I just need to store 2 value. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Multi value Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569903/multi-value-dictionary)

Comment: Thanks i did not find that when I search.

Answer (score 0):

If you need variable number of values per key, you can use

```
Dictionary<TypeOfKey, List<TypeOfValue>
```

E.g. if you want to store an arbitrary number of integers per string, you could do this

```
var numbersPerString = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary values can be an arbitrary type, so make the values structs with appropriate members, then you'll be able to store two, or as many as you like.

I don't know if C# has an equivalent to C++ std::pair; you could use that, but a struct might make more sense, then you can say:

```
dict[person].shoesize
dict[person].eyecolour
```

Which is nice and readable.