# Filling a multi-value dictionary with query results

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, collections, generics

I am retrieving five columns through an SQL query. Among the columns retrieved, I have a column *RecordID* which should act as a **key** to a dictionary.

I am referring to the solution posted: [C# Multi-Value Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569903/multi-value-dictionary) at StackOverflow, but I am not able to use it effectively depending upon my situation.

I want to store all the rows of my query but the RecordID column should also act as a key to the dictionary element. I want something like:

```
Dictionary<RecordID, Entire columns of the current row for this RecordID>
```

An alternative I think is to use an array, something like:

```
Dictionary<key,string[]>
```

But I want to use any super-fast way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) - you haven't said much about the data, but you may need something as simple as:

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup(x => x.RecordID);
```

There are, of course, overloads for [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) which allow you to do other things.

Comment: @Jon: Please may I know what you want to know about the data? Do you want to see the SQL Query?

Comment: @RPK: Well it's not clear what values you're trying to get out, or whether you're using LINQ to start with (as the grouping can probably be done in the database transparently) etc. Basically we have no idea what your current code looks like. But `ToLookup` should be your friend either way...

Comment: @Jon I am picking rows through SQL into a DataSet. The entire row consists of columns like: RecordID, ItemID, ItemName, SalePrice, AvailableQty.

Comment: @RPK: Any reason why you're not using LINQ to start with? Anyway, you should be able to use `ToLookup` with the dataset easily enough. You might want to call `DataTable.AsEnumerable()` to get an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` first.

Comment: @Jon: Is DataTable heavier than an ordinary Dictionary?

Comment: @RPK: They're completely different data structures. These days I personally try to avoid using DataSet/DataTable etc.

Answer (score 0):

Oh goodness sake, you need a dedicated class to hold the values. Since the columns are from a db table the number of fields is fixed. Hence you can have a class with fixed fields rather than a dynamically growing collection. And lastly use a `KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>` structure to hold a collection of records. In a `KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>` the `TKey` part is embedded in the `TItem`, in your case its `RecordId`.

```
class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //rest of the fields
}
```

Your structure should look like `KeyedCollection<int, Record>`. It preserves insertion order as well. You can query the collection using `RecordId` via indexer, just like a dictionary.