# Better alternative to nesting dictionaries for lookup tables

Tags: c#, design-patterns, lookup-tables

When building lookup tables that exceed a single dimension I find myself nesting dictionaries a lot:

```
public class MyLookupTable
{
    IDictionary<T1, IDictionary<T2, ISet<T3>>> mapOfMapOfSequences;

    // Update the table
    public void AddItem(T3 myItem);

    // Access the table
    public IEnumerable<T3> GetItems(T1 key1, T2 key2);
}
```

This has been working great for me so far, despite needing to write some wordy ContainsKey conditionals to access/modify the table.

Recently I am writing a caching mechanism that has 5 keys, and the dictionary field definition is a little ridiculous.

Architecturally, is there a design pattern I am completely overlooking that would make this problem a little more manageable?

Comment: [Possible duplcate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303859/is-a-deep-nested-dictionary-an-antipattern)

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: It looks like you're doing fine. You have a custom type wrapping the dictionaries to be used properly (I'm assuming seeing the snippet you provided) and dictionaries are quite fast for lookup and storage. Personally  I wouldn't suggest a better way unless I saw all the code and even then I'm sure you're doing it just fine.

Comment: For your case a compound key would likely make sense.  However it depends on the use case.  If for example you need to know how many secondary key values exist for a given primary key then the nested form would make that operation more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

[`ValueTuples`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/) are helpful in creating ad-hoc types for scenarios like yours.

You could declare a dictionary like this:

```
IDictionary<(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5), TValue> dictionary;
```

Add values like this

```
dictionary.Add((k1, k2, k3, k4, k5), value);
```

You can find and example in the article [Dissecting the tuples in C# 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/11/01/dissecting-the-tuples-in-c-7/) (MSDN).

You can also name the tuple items

```
IDictionary<(T1 key1, T2 key2, T3 key3, T4 key4, T5 key5), TValue> dictionary;

dictionary.Add((key1: k1, key2: k2, key3: k3, key4: k4, key5: k5), value);
```

Of course, you would choose speaking names adapted to your problem. Given a key, you can then access the tuple items like this:

```
var key = dictionary.Keys.First();
T3 k3 = key.key3;
```

or deconstruct the key with

```
var (k1, k2, k3, k4, k5) = dictionary.Keys.First();
Console.WriteLine($"Key 3 is {k3}");
```

---

C# 9 introduced [record types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records)

ValueTuples are good to be used locally; however, they are anonymous. If you want to expose a type in an API, then record classes or record structs are a better solution.

The C# compiler automatically creates the infrastructure required for dictionary keys. Among other things, it overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and makes the record immutable.

All you need to write is something like this:

```cs
public readonly record struct MyKey(T1 Key1, T2 Key2, T3 Key3);
```

This creates a so called primary constructor with these 3 parameters as well as the whole body of the struct including 3 Key properties.

Comment: Such a clean solution, especially since it solves the rather unsolvable problem of returning nested dictionaries AsReadOnly()