# Why would you use an immutable value in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, dictionary

The multiple answers to question "[Multi value Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569903/multi-value-dictionary)" propose to use an immutable class as `TValue` in [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) Class.

The accepted [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/569920/2031316) proposes a class `Pair` with readonly properties and [@teedyay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/569921/2031316) to use the immutable [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx).

What is the rationale (or the possible benefits) of such approaches?

And collateral question:
Why [to make TFirst and TSecond readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/569920/200449) if the respective properties First and Second do not have setters anyway:

```
private readonly TFirst first;
private readonly TSecond second;

public TFirst First
{
   get { return first; }
}

public TSecond Second
{
   get { return second; }
}
```

**Update:**
I am using dictionaries with custom classes for values in them.
And the va lues are being updated.
What are the possible reasons (benefits) for me to make them immutable?

I see that [`Lookup<TKey, TElement> Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) is also immutable and thought that I miss some benefits of using LINQ queries (?)
If so, can you give me examples what do I miss?

Comment: First might not have a setter but that doesn't restrict you from setting first directly if its not read only.

Comment: As for teedyay's answer, it could be that the immutability of `Tuple` is incidental, and `Tuple` is just the simplest way to pair the two values together. Could be that it's also incidental in Jon Skeet's answer as he posted code for a `Pair` type that he wrote for another occasion.

Comment: I agree with @DanielFischer, I just think it was incidental to the conversation, especially as his implementation provides an override of GetHashCode.  There are warnings about overriding GetHashCode on mutable types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second question's answer is that the member variables are still settable without the `readonly` keyword - only within the class itself, but it is still possible.

BTW, this class seems like a solid candidate for a `struct`.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, immutability makes various things easier to read about in my experience. For example, one of the big pain points in Java's `Calendar` and `Date` classes is their mutability. It's all to easy to forget they're mutable, take a copy of a *reference* in the constructor, and then find that something else mutates the object you've got a reference to. So you start taking a defensive copy even if nothing *is* going to change the object... it all gets very annoying.

There's a time for mutability, of course - but in many cases immutability is simply nicer.