# Dictionary as value to one key in another dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I dont how to added dictionary contain multiple items to another dictionary as value

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,double>> proptest=new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,double>>
if (proptest.ContainsKey(filenametest))
                {

                    proptest[filenametest].Add(filenametraining, NB) ;
                }
                else
                {
                    proptest.Add(filenametest, new Dictionary<string, double> { { filenametraining, NB } });
                }
```

the result is:
{[10171.txt, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Double]]}
while I want result is:
{[10171.txt: (cat10 0.4) (cat3 0.6)]}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi value Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569903/multi-value-dictionary), you could also go with [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: What is problem? Can you be more specific?

Comment: how can I added dictionary as value to one key in another dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an existing dictionary like this:

```
// The 'outer' dictionary:
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>();

// an existing 'inner' dictionary:
var innerDictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, double> { 
    { "inner1.1", 6 }, { "inner1.2", 4.5 } 
};

// add the inner to the outer:
myDictionary.Add("outer1", innerDictionary1);
```

To add an 'inner' dictionary inline:

```
myDictionary.Add("outer2", 
    new Dictionary<string, double> { 
        { "inner2.1", 3.48748}, { "inner2.2", 25 }, { "inner2.3", 0 } 
    });
```

Also, if you wanted to add values to an inner dictionary, you could do this:

```
myDictionary["outer2"].Add("inner2.4", 3.56);
```